# How to loop through columns and calculate averages?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

[image: Data series][data series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5S4g.png)

I want to find the average for each segment of ten values down a column. (See data series picture) 
Continuously all the way to the bottom of the data set. The data set can vary in length, and the code has to be "generic" of sorts.

Based on other code segments I have tried to do this:

```
Sub tenthavg()

Dim currentIndex As Long
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim rng As Range

ReDim myArray(1 To 10)     

Range("b1", Range("b1").End(xlDown)).Select
Set myArray = Selection        
currentIndex = 1

Do Until currentIndex + 1 > UBound(myArray)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(currentIndex, "T") = AverageOfSubArray(myArray, currentIndex, 10)
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
Loop                   

End Sub

'=================================================================

Function AverageOfSubArray(myArray As Variant, startIndex As Long,   elementCount As Long) As Double
Dim runningTotal As Double
Dim i As Long

For i = startIndex To (startIndex + elementCount - 1)
    runningTotal = runningTotal + val(myArray(i))
Next i
AverageOfSubArray = runningTotal / elementCount
End Function
```

Unfortunately I can't make it work. Am I approaching this the right way?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just realized that you have already found / accepted an answer. So, there is no point on me updating my answer.

Comment: Your post was very informative - a great resource. Shouldn't be removed

Comment: My mind works pretty simple: you like one of my posts `-->` you up-vote it (to show your appreciation) and the post stays. No up-votes tells me that my post is of no use and it gets removed. Simple. Just upon some rare occasions I still leave my post around whenever I want to keep them as a personal note. So, next time you like a post on this site just make sure you up-vote it and I'm pretty sure the post will not get removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO it's not quite the successful approach ... instead of `Select`ing `EndDown` and other concepts borrowed from interactive working make use of VBA's own mechanisms.

A "generic" approch takes Range start address, batch size and offsets where to put the result as arguments ...

```
Sub AvgX(MyR As Range, S As Integer, ORow As Integer, OCol As Integer)
' MyR = start of range
' S   = batch size
' OCol, ORow = Offsets to place result in relation to last batch value
Dim Idx As Integer, Jdx As Integer, RSum As Variant

    Idx = 1
    RSum = 0
    Do
        For Jdx = 1 To S
            RSum = RSum + MyR(Idx, 1)
            Idx = Idx + 1
            If MyR(Idx, 1) = "" Then Exit Do
        Next Jdx
        MyR(Idx - 1, 1).Offset(ORow, OCol) = RSum / (Jdx - 1)
        RSum = 0
    Loop
End Sub
```

and is called by

```
Sub Test()
    AvgX [C4], 10, 0, 1
End Sub
```

to give you this result ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result in a simpler way:

```
Sub tenthavg()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Columns(2).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Dim myArray(1 To 10) As Double

If LastRow < 10 Then
    MsgBox "There's not enough data!"
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    For x = 1 To LastRow - 9
        For y = 1 To 10
            myArray(y) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Cells(y + x - 1, 2).Value
        Next y
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Cells(x, 20).FormulaR1C1 = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Cells(x, 20).FormulaR1C1 = Application.Average(myArray)
    Next x
End If

End Sub
```

Please note: I'm assuming you're data starts at `B1` and you want the output on column `T`.

Comment: Although this probably works just fine, you are accessing a cell on the worksheet three times for every one cell in column B. That could add up very quickly and slow things down a lot.